# Volta uninstall node does not work anymore! Anybody knows how to do this now?

Tags: node.js, volta

I run this command:
[image]

And i don't know how remove node versions with volta.

The official site don't say how do this:

[image]

I want remove all volta node versions but i don't know how to do this now:
[image]

Anybody hace an idea to how to do this ? Please help

I ran this command:
[image]

I expected that node was uninstalled successfully

Comment: Hey @Richard, volta can only uninstall packages like angular-cli, not the node runtimes & package managers like npm

Comment: Hey @Richard, what works for me and others in the community is to remove every version in the ~/.volta/tools/image/node/ which contains all versions of the node installed.